# Symfony form throw error : cannot instantiate trait

Tags: php, forms, symfony, traits

I have an error on an edit form that only happens in the production environment. I use Symfony 2.6.3 on a PHP 5.4.10/Apache 2.4.4 server.

I can't repdroduce the bug in dev environement.

Here is the trace :

```
php.EMERGENCY: Fatal Error: Cannot instantiate trait (null) {"type":1,"file":"/app/list/home/appadm01/Corsaire/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php","line":184,"level":22527,"stack":[]} []
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: "Error: Cannot instantiate trait (null)" at /app/list/home/appadm01/Corsaire/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php line 184 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException(code: 0): Error: Cannot instantiate trait (null) at /app/list/home/appadm01/Corsaire/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php:184)"} []
```

So i looked at the Form.php file at line 184 :

```
        $this->children = new OrderedHashMap();
```

and the constructor of OrderedHashMap is :

```
public function __construct(array $elements = array())
{
    $this->elements = $elements;
    $this->orderedKeys = array_keys($elements);
}
```

I don't understand why this error happen ... there is no "use" inside the class.
So here is the Form Type :

```
namespace Silca\CorsaireRefCotBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Silca\CorsaireRefCotBundle\Entity\Application;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class ApplicationType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('codeAppli', null, array(
                'label' => 'Code applicatif'
            ))
            ->add('nomAppli', null, array(
                'label' => 'Nom de l\'application'
            ))
            ->add('description', null, array(
                'label' => 'Description'
            ))
            ->add('dICP', null, array(
                'label' => 'DICP'
            ))
            ->add('nVCP', null, array(
                'label' => 'NVCP'
            ))
            ->add('compServeur',null, array(
                'label' => 'Composant serveur'
            ))
            ->add('compRelation', null, array(
                'label' => 'Composant relation'
            ))
            ->add('compBDD', null, array(
                'label' => 'Composant BDD'
            ))
            ->add('txDispo', 'percent', array(
                'type' => 'integer',
                'label' => 'Taux de disponibilité',
                'required'  => false
            ))
            ->add('exploitabilite', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => Application::getTypesExploit(),
                'label' => 'Exploitabilité',
                'expanded' => true,
                'required'  => false,
                'empty_value' => 'N/A'
                ))
            ->add('dIMA', null, array(
                'label' => 'DIMA'
            ))
            ->add('pDMA', null, array(
                'label' => 'PDMA'
            ))
            ->add('critique', 'choice', array(
                'label' => 'Application critique ?',
                'choices' => Application::getTypesCritique(),
                'expanded' => true
            ))
            ->add('dateOuverture', 'date', array(
                'widget' => 'text',
                'format' => 'ddMMyyyy',
                'label' => 'Date d\'ouverture (Jour/Mois/Année)',
                'invalid_message' => 'La date n\'est pas correcte'
            ))
            ->add('dateFermeture', 'date', array(
                'widget' => 'text',
                'format' => 'ddMMyyyy',
                'required' => false,
                'empty_data' => null,
                'label' => 'Date de fermeture (Jour/Mois/Année)',
                'invalid_message' => 'La date n\'est pas correcte'
            ))
            ->add('domaine', null, array(
                'label' => 'Domaine'
            ))
            ->add('gtr', null, array(
                'label' => 'GTR'
            ))
            ->add('plagedeservice', null, array(
                'label' => 'Plage de service'
            ))
            ->add('client', null,array(
                'label' => 'Client'
            ))
            ->add('iemNominal', "entity", array(
                'class' => 'Silca\CorsaireUtilisateurBundle\Entity\Utilisateur',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')->join('u.equipe', 'e')->where('e INSTANCE OF Silca\CorsaireRefCotBundle\Entity\Exploit')->orderBy('u.nom', 'ASC');
                    },
                'group_by' => 'equipe',
                'empty_value' =>"",
                'label' => 'IEM Nominal',
                'required'  => false
            ))
            ->add('moe', null, array(
                'attr' => array("onchange"=>'enableMoe()'),
                'label' => 'MOE'
            ))
            ->add('exploit',null, array(
                'attr' => array("onchange"=>'enableExploit()'),
                'label' => 'Equipe d\'exploitation'
            ))
            ->add('iems', "entity", array(
                'class' => 'Silca\CorsaireUtilisateurBundle\Entity\Utilisateur',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')->join('u.equipe', 'e')->where('e INSTANCE OF Silca\CorsaireRefCotBundle\Entity\Exploit')->orderBy('u.nom', 'ASC');
                    },
                'group_by' => 'equipe',
                'empty_value' =>"",
                'multiple' => true,
                'label' => 'Ingenieur d\'exploitation',
                'required'  => false
            ))
            ->add('cdp', "entity", array(
                'class' => 'Silca\CorsaireUtilisateurBundle\Entity\Utilisateur',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')->join('u.equipe', 'e')->where('e INSTANCE OF Silca\CorsaireRefCotBundle\Entity\Moe')->orderBy('u.nom', 'ASC');
                    },
                'group_by' => 'equipe',
                'empty_value' =>"",
                'label' => 'Chargé de projet',
                'required'  => false
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Silca\CorsaireRefCotBundle\Entity\Application'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'silca_corsairerefcotbundle_application';
    }
}
```

and the controller :

```
public function editAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('SilcaCorsaireRefCotBundle:Application')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Application entity.');
    }

    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return $this->render('SilcaCorsaireRefCotBundle:Application:edit.html.twig', array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
    }

    private function createEditForm(Application $entity)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new ApplicationType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('application_update', array('id' => $entity->getId())),
            'method' => 'PUT',
        ));

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Mettre à jour'));

        return $form;
    }
```

if someone see something strange, thanks for help !

Comment: If the problem is on production and not development I see only 3 things to check : 1. Clear the production cache 2. Check if the PHP version on production is the same than the one on development 3. Check if the vendors are the same in production and development

Comment: Yes, I already checked those. Cache cleared, environments are identical

Comment: Very strange ... When you test with dev mode, it's on the same machine than the production with app_dev.php ?

Comment: No the production environment are on a dedicated server

Comment: You should try if it works with the app_dev.php URL on your server (you have to modify the file to bypass the IP security, don't forget to remove these modifications after your test). You will have a better debug stack trace with that.

Comment: Ok, I did it, and it works fine in debug mode ...